# Can Java enum take values with a suffix?

Tags: java, enums

I want to create enum values with suffix, something like this:

```
enum PersonType{
  Teacher, Staff, Student.junior, Student.senior; 
}
```

Is there some way to express the need such the "Student" with a suffix? Or I have to use totally separate values for it?

Comment: What is wrong with using separate values?

Comment: No, Java does not have a feature to do exactly what you want.

Comment: They are related values and make its semantics more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more solution

```
public interface PersonType {}

public enum StudentType implements PersonType {
   Senior, Junior;
}

public enum SimplePerson implements PersonType {
    Teacher, Staff;
}
```

And use this way:

```
PersonType type1 = StudentType.Junior;
PersonType type2 = SimplePerson.Staff;
```

Comment: Nice, although I'm not sure teachers and staff would appreciate being called "simple"...

Answer (score 2):

Enum constants follow the same rules as any identifier in Java.

According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-EnumConstant) :

> **8.9.1. Enum Constants**
>
> EnumConstant:
>
> {EnumConstantModifier} **Identifier** [( [ArgumentList] )] [ClassBody]

And [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) is the specification of an identifier :

> **3.8. Identifiers**
>
> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

...

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024). The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy
>   systems.
>
> The "Java digits" include the ASCII digits 0-9 (\u0030-\u0039).

So, the `.` character is not allowed to identify an enum constant.
But the `_` character that may be seen as a separator is allowed. You could use it.

At last, enum constants should be written in uppercase to respect Java naming conventions :

```
enum PersonType{
  TEACHAR, STAFF, STUDENT_JUNIOR, STUDENT_SENIOR; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a "flat" enumeration of types, and might be better modeled as a class hierarchy, but assuming you want `enum`, you can include all values explicitly in the enum, and add attributes to model the fact that several of them are "students".

```
public enum PersonType {

    Teacher(false), Staff(false), JuniorStudent(true), SeniorStudent(true);

    final boolean isStudent;

    PersonType(boolean isStudent) {
        this.isStudent = isStudent;
    }

    boolean isStudent() {
        return isStudent;
    }
}
```

Or, without attributes, you could rely on your own convention, for example like so (but without dots):

```
public enum PersonType {

    Teacher, Staff, JuniorStudent, SeniorStudent;

    boolean isStudent() {
        return name().endsWith("Student");
    }
}
```

(although the general convention suggests to use uppercase names for enums)